# Connecting to each DB2 platform through .NET

Tags: c#, .net, db2

Recently I started working in an application that needs to write and read from a DB2 database and until now, I've never used DB2.

Reading on the internet, I got some information and have made some assumptions. I just need to know if what I am thinking is correct, or if there's another way.

- With IBM Data Provider (.net DLLs) I can only connect do DB2 running on linux or Windows servers.
- For DB2 running on as/400, z/os, iS, I can use these same DLLs BUT(!) it's
  necessary to use 'DB2 Connect' to accomplish this.
- If I don't have  'DB2 Connect' I can ONLY connect to databases running on as/400, z/os or iS, if I use OLEDB or ODBC.

Sorry if I misunderstood something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect to DB2 for i on Power Systems (formerly known as AS/400 or iSeries) with the .NET Data Provider that comes with IBM i Access (formerly IBM iSeries Access).  DB2 Connect  is not required for this platform.

Make sure that your version of [IBM i Access for Windows](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/windows.html) (or IBM iSeries Access) is greater or equal to the version of IBM i (formerly known as OS/400 or i5/OS), and that it has the correct [service pack](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/windows_sp.html) installed.

Comment: first, thanks for your time and reply. So, with IBM i, i can connect to DB2 hosted on Windows and Linux too? I can say that, these IBM i Access package is all i need to work with DB2 on all platforms? Today, i already made a simple program, connecting to DB2 on my windows server. But i am using the dlls shipped with DB2 Express C.
Is there a difference between the dlls shipped with DB2 express and these on IBM i package?

Comment: [IBM Data Server Provider for .NET](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.net_cc.doc%2Fcom.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.doc%2Fdoc%2Fc0010960.htm) these files that i am using actually. And where my doubts come.

Comment: Watch the supported release levels for each platform you are connecting to.  The levels shown are current for IBM i, and I believe for z/OS, presumably for LUW too considering the source is from the group that produces DB2 LUW. (DB2 for i is from a different group in IBM, which may be why it is harder to find information about it from the Information Management Group's DB2 pages and their products sometimes do not mention support for current releases of IBM i. I am pleased to see this one *does* cover v5r4 through 7.1)